# "Square Root of 2" : Decimal System vs. Sexagesimal Systems?

Tags: number-theory, approximation

**Does the "Square Root of 2" have "Less Significance" in the Decimal System compared to other Number Systems?**

Recently, I learned that the Babylonian Civilization has a number system of "base 60" (sexagesimal) compared to "base 10" (decimal):

[image]

I always wondered where the need would have come to specifically calculate the "Square Root of 2" - is this because somehow "square root of 2" naturally comes up a lot more frequently in the sexagesimal system compared to the decimal system? And does anyone why the specific numbers 24, 51, 10 appear in the above formula?

Thanks!

Comment: You should at least mention that you have posted a connected question [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14140/3730) with the same exceirpt.

Comment: Of course, try writing down square root of 2 in the base square root of 2 instead of decimal. Many things in many bases are trivial compared to decimal system.

Comment: No, $\sqrt{2}$ is just an interesting number (it has a clear geometrical meaning). And it's non-trivial to calculate it in any base (with integer base at least).